# in symfony project, in the controller of a Booking entity, I want to check if the user has a role, and then redirect them, what is going error

Tags: symfony, controller, roles, tostring

In this function **onAuthenticationSuccess** I have the following code to check if the user has a certain role and then i tried to redirect him to the right path, but it seems to be not working, is there another way to do that?

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, string $firewallName): ?Response

    {
        if ($targetPath = $this->getTargetPath($request->getSession(), $firewallName)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
        }

        // Redirecten afhankkelijk van de user role:
        $user = $token->getUser();


        if (in_array("ROLE_GAST", $user->getRoles(), true)) {
            return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('gast_profile'));
        }
        else if (in_array("ROLE_MEDEWERKER", $user->getRoles(), true)){
            return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_medewerker'));
        }
        else if (in_array("ROLE_ADMIN", $user->getRoles())){
            return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_admin'));
        }



        // For example:
        return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_home'));
        // throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl(Request $request): string
    {
        return $this->urlGenerator->generate(self::LOGIN_ROUTE);
    }
```

I tried this:
**Convert to string error**

I went to entity all the way down and i added this:

```
    public function __toString() {
        
                return $this->name;
            }
```

Comment: There is no need to get the user in this case. $token->getRoleNames() will give you the roles.  I was puzzled by your response to the answer below.  Do you users have the proper roles? `not working` is really not a very useful description of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

do not check the roles with in_array like this

```
$hasAccess = in_array('ROLE_ADMIN', $user->getRoles());
```

check the manual out

https://symfony.com/doc/5.4/security.html#roles

as you can see the best practice is to define the roles in your securtiy config like this

```
// config/packages/security.yaml
security:
    # ...

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_INSTRUCTOR: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_MEMBER: ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_INSTRUCTOR, ROLE_MEMBER]
```

then you can check the roles like this

```
$hasAccess = $this->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN');
$this->denyAccessUnlessGranted('ROLE_ADMIN');
```

Answer (score -1):

## Make user auth:

### Step 4: Create User Class

We will then create a user class, by using the ***make:user*** command – this command will create a User class for security and it will automatically update the ***security.yaml***.

Follow these steps:

```
php bin/console make:user       
 
 The name of the security user class (e.g. User) [User]:
 >
 
 Do you want to store user data in the database (via Doctrine)? (yes/no) [yes]:
 >
 
 Enter a property name that will be the unique "display" name for the user (e.g. email, username, uuid) [email]:
 >
 
 Will this app need to hash/check user passwords? Choose No if passwords are not needed or will be checked/hashed by some other system (e.g. a single sign-on server).
 
 Does this app need to hash/check user passwords? (yes/no) [yes]:
 >
 
 created: src/Entity/User.php
 created: src/Repository/UserRepository.php
 updated: src/Entity/User.php
 updated: config/packages/security.yaml
 
  
  Success! 
  
 
 Next Steps:
   - Review your new App\Entity\User class.
   - Use make:entity to add more fields to your User entity and then run make:migration.
   - Create a way to authenticate! See https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html
```

### Step 5: Create Migration

Then we will create a migration file and then migrate it:

Execute this command to create a migration file:

```
php bin/console make:migration
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

### Step 6: Create Login

To create login on Symfony 5, we can use the ***make:auth*** command – this command can provide empty authenticator or a full login form authentication process depending of what you have chosen.

Execute this command and follow the steps below:
php bin/console make:auth

```
 What style of authentication do you want? [Empty authenticator]:
  [0] Empty authenticator
  [1] Login form authenticator
 > 1
1
 
 The class name of the authenticator to create (e.g. AppCustomAuthenticator):
 > AppCustomAuthenticator
 
 Choose a name for the controller class (e.g. SecurityController) [SecurityController]:
 >
 
 Do you want to generate a '/logout' URL? (yes/no) [yes]:
 >
 
 created: src/Security/AppCustomAuthenticator.php
 updated: config/packages/security.yaml
 created: src/Controller/SecurityController.php
 created: templates/security/login.html.twig
 
            
  Success! 
            
 
 Next:
 - Customize your new authenticator.
 - Finish the redirect "TODO" in the App\Security\AppCustomAuthenticator::onAuthenticationSuccess() method.
 - Check the user's password in App\Security\AppCustomAuthenticator::checkCredentials().
 - Review & adapt the login template: templates/security/login.html.twig.
```

After following the steps above, open the file ***‘src\Security\AppCustomAuthenticator.php’*** and update a part of the code:

***src\Security\AppCustomAuthenticator.php***

change it:

```
see manage roles
```

### Step 7: Create Registration

After creating the Login we will then create the Registration. We can use the ***make:registration*** command.

Execute this command and follow the steps below:

```
php bin/console make:registration
 
 Creating a registration form for App\Entity\User
 
 Do you want to add a @UniqueEntity validation annotation on your User class to make sure duplicate accounts aren't created? (yes/no) [yes]:
 > 
 
 Do you want to send an email to verify the user's email address after registration? (yes/no) [yes]:
 > no
 
 Do you want to automatically authenticate the user after registration? (yes/no) [yes]:
 >
 
 ! [NOTE] No Guard authenticators found - so your user won't be automatically authenticated after registering.
 
 What route should the user be redirected to after registration?:
  [0 ] _wdt
  [1 ] _profiler_home
  [2 ] _profiler_search
  [3 ] _profiler_search_bar
  [4 ] _profiler_phpinfo
  [5 ] _profiler_search_results
  [6 ] _profiler_open_file
  [7 ] _profiler
  [8 ] _profiler_router
  [9 ] _profiler_exception
  [10] _profiler_exception_css
  [11] dashboard
  [12] app_login
  [13] app_logout
  [14] _preview_error
 > 11
11
 
 updated: src/Entity/User.php
 created: src/Form/RegistrationFormType.php
 created: src/Controller/RegistrationController.php
 created: templates/registration/register.html.twig
 
            
  Success! 
            
 
 Next:
 Make any changes you need to the form, controller & template.
 
 Then open your browser, go to "/register" and enjoy your new form!
```

See the source documentation in this link:
[https://www.binaryboxtuts.com/php-tutorials/how-to-make-a-user-login-and-register-in-symfony-5/][1]

## manage roles

- after makeing the auth  go to:

  app\src\Controller\RegistrationController.php

and add this:

```
$user->setRoles(['ROLE_MEMBER']);
```

So above:

```
$user->setRoles(['ROLE_MEMBER']);
$entityManager->persist($user);
$entityManager->flush();
```

next go to:

```
App\Security\LoginAuthenticator::onAuthenticationSuccess() method.
```

and change todo:

here is the code om te redirecten afjankelijk van de role:

````
    //get the user
    $user = $token->getUser();
    
    if (in_array("ROLE_INSTRUCTOR", $user->getRoles(), true)) {
                return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_instructor'));
            }
            else if (in_array("ROLE_MEMBER", $user->getRoles(), true)){
                return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_member'));
            }
            else if (in_array("ROLE_ADMIN", $user->getRoles())){
                return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_admin'));
            }
    
    // For example:
            return new RedirectResponse($this->urlGenerator->generate('app_bezoeker'));
            // throw new \Exception('TODO: provide a valid redirect inside '.__FILE__);
    ```


  [1]: https://www.binaryboxtuts.com/php-tutorials/how-to-make-a-user-login-and-register-in-symfony-5/
````

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the source, it helped me making the user authentication, So how can you get the **info of user** and send them to twig template

Comment: So you copied/pasted a complete tutorial and then copied the question at the end?  At first I thought this was some sort of ChatGPT thing.  Not sure which is worse.

Comment: Hello, it looks like all your answers are copy pastes from tutorials rather than **specific** answers for specific questions. Please stop and answer the questions directly.

Answer (score -1):

Show user info

Here is how you can show the user info:

```
#[Route('/gast/profile', name: 'gast_profile')]
    public function index(UserRepository $userRepository,): Response
    {
       
        $title = "Profile";
        return $this->render('gast/profile.html.twig', [
            'title' => $title,
        ]);
    }
```

Show it in the twig with just:

```
app.user
app.user.name
etc..
```

Edit user

```
// edit user
    #[Route('/gast/profile/{id}/edit', name: 'gast_profile_edit')]
    public function register(Request $request, User $user, UserRepository $userRepository, UserPasswordHasherInterface $userPasswordHasher,): Response
    {
       
        $form = $this->createForm(RegistrationFormType::class, $user);
        // add submit botton custom
        $form->add('Wijzigen', SubmitType::class, array(
            'label' => 'Wijzigen',
        ));
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            // encode the plain password
            $user->setPassword(
                $userPasswordHasher->hashPassword(
                    $user,
                    $form->get('plainPassword')->getData()
                )
            );
            $userRepository->save($user, true);
           
        }

        return $this->render('registration/register.html.twig', [
            'registrationForm' => $form->createView(),
        ]);
    }
```

Get booking of the user:

```
$bookings = $this->getuser()->getBookings();
```

Add booking:

```
#[Route('/gast/boekingen/add', name: 'gast_boekings_add')]
    public function addGastBookings(UserRepository $userRepository, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager,  Request $request,  UserInterface $user): Response
    {   
                // get current user
        $user = $this->getUser();

        $booking = new Booking();
        $form = $this->createForm(BookingType::class, $booking);
        $form->handleRequest($request);
        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                        // setting the currrent user
            $booking->setUser($user);
            $entityManager->persist($booking);
            $entityManager->flush();

            return $this->redirectToRoute('gast_boekings');
        }

        $title = "Add booking";
        return $this->renderForm('gast/add.html.twig', [
            'title' => $title,
            'form' => $form,
        ]);
    }
```

The form in BookingType builder:

```
$builder
            ->add('date', DateType::class, [
                'widget' => 'choice',
            ])
            ->add('time', TimeType::class, [
                'input'  => 'datetime',
                'widget' => 'choice',
            ])
            // User is setted from the controller: $booking->setUser($user);

            ->add('donkey_adventure', EntityType::class, [
                // looks for choices from this entity
                'class' => DonkeyAdventure::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
            ])
            ->add('Add', SubmitType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'save btn-primary'],
            ])
        ;
    }
```

Edit booking:

```
$builder
            ->add('date', DateType::class, [
                'widget' => 'choice',
            ])
            ->add('time', TimeType::class, [
                'input'  => 'datetime',
                'widget' => 'choice',
            ])
            // User is setted from the controller: $booking->setUser($user);

            ->add('donkey_adventure', EntityType::class, [
                // looks for choices from this entity
                'class' => DonkeyAdventure::class,
                'choice_label' => 'name',
            ])
            ->add('Add', SubmitType::class, [
                'attr' => ['class' => 'save btn-primary'],
            ])
        ;
    }
```

Delete booking

```
//delete booking
    #[Route('/gast/boekingen/{id}/delete', name: 'gast_boekings_delete')]
    public function deleteGastBookings(UserRepository $userRepository, Booking $booking, Request $request, EntityManagerInterface $entityManager): Response
    {
        $entityManager->remove($booking);
        $entityManager->flush();
        $this->addFlash(
            'success',
            'De boeking is verwijderd!'
         );
        
        return $this->redirectToRoute('gast_boekings');
    }
```

Bootstrap style 1:

```
<div class="row my-4">
        <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Update Room
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    {{form(form)}}

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Bootstrap style2

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row my-5">
        <div class="col-md-10 mx-auto">
            {% for message in app.flashes('success') %}
                <div class="alert alert-success">
                    {{ message }}
                </div>
             {% endfor %}
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                    <span>List of rooms</span>
                    <a href="{{path('room_create')}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                        Add
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <table class="table table-borderd table-hover">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>ID</th>
                                <th>TITLE</th>
                                <th>DESCRIPTION</th>
                                <th>IMAGE</th>
                                <th>PRICE</th>
                                <th>NUMBER</th>
                                <th>ACTION</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {% for room in rooms %}
                                <tr>
                                    <td>{{loop.index}}</td>
                                    <td>{{room.title}}</td>
                                    <td>{{room.description}}</td>
                                    <td>
                                        {% if room.image %}
                                            <img src="{{asset('uploads/'~room.image)}}" alt="{{room.title}}"  width="60" height="60" class="fluid my-2 rounded">
                                            {% else %}
                                            <img src="{{asset('uploads/default.jpg')}}" alt="{{room.title}}"  width="60" height="60" class="fluid my-2 rounded">
                                        {% endif %}
                                    </td>
                                    <td>{{room.price}}</td>
                                    <td>{{room.number}}</td>
                                    <td class="d-flex justify-content-around  ">
                                        <a href="{{path('room_show', {id: room.id})}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-dark">Show <i class="fa-solid fa-eye"></i></a>
                                        <a href="{{path('room_edit', {id: room.id})}}" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning">Edit <i class="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i></a>
                                        <form id="{{room.id}}" action="{{path('room_delete', {id: room.id})}}" method="POST"></form>
                                        <button onclick="deleteItem('{{room.id}}')" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">Delete <i class="fa-solid fa-trash"></i></button>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>

                            {% endfor %}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

To work with forms

```
composer require symfony/form
php bin/console make:form
```

and then give the e.g BookingType, give class Booking

Herere to find form types choices:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types.html

Get bookings van de user in controller

```
$bookings = $this->getuser()->getBookings();
```

Convert date and time in twig:

```
<td>{{booking.date|date("d-m-y")}}</td>
<td>{{booking.time|date('H:i:s')}}</td>
```

Comment: Hello, I fail to see how most of these are directly related to the question. Could you explain?